# How to maintain gmail session when we switch to google drive using capybara

Tags: ruby, rspec, automation, capybara, browser-automation

Via automation using rspec and capybara I want to create a new folder name as 'xyz' on to the google drive but when i switch to drive and click on 'new' button, it shows that 'your are not signed in'.
How i could maintain the session or how should i use switch to new window function properly.

My code is :

```
def drive_management

    find(:xpath, gmail_google_app).click
    gen_wait_less
    find(:xpath, $gmail_drive_link).click
    gen_wait_more
    login_window = window_opened_by do
      click_button $gmail_drive_link
    end
   within_window(login_window) do
     find(:xpath, $gmail_new_button).click
     gen_wait_more
     find(:xpath, $gmail_new_folder).click
     gen_wait_more
   end
```

Comment: Maintain what session?  If you haven't yet logged into google you would have to login.

Comment: Thomas, i have already logged in, but when my script click on gmail drive icon and new tab gets opened.When i try to perform any operation on drive like Creating a folder etc, it says you need to sign in whereas i have already logged in

Comment: Already logged in during this test/automation session, or you've logged in manually in the browser and are expecting that session to be there during the automation session?  Maybe you need to show move of your code where it logs in, and define what gen_wait_more/less are doing